# openCV waitkey() not responding, and runtime VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to do basic video capture from a webcam. I got this very basic code from this [opencv blog](http://opencv-srf.blogspot.in/2011/09/capturing-images-videos.html) and I'm compiling it with

```
 g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` test2.cpp `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

And when I run it, it shows me these messages

```
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
VIDIOC_QUERYMENU: Invalid argument
```

but it does run. However, the program is supposed to exit when the esc key is pressed. Because of this line

```
if(waitKey(30) == 27)
```

But it does not. I tried changing it in the program, to some other key, like 'q', but it still doesn't work when I run the program.

```
if(waitKey(30) == 'q')
```

While running, it seems that waitkey() just isn't responding.

EDIT : waitKey() works. When I copied it, for some reason it became waitkey(). However, the invalid argument messages are still being shown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OpenCV sometimes does not work well with some cameras. That code in that blog work fine with my webcam without any warning messages

Comment: oh, okay, I'll check it out with a different webcam then